# unterminated `s' command error - trying to remove extra double quote

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to edit a single row in a text file, by removing an unnecessary double quote in front of the name, i.e. "THE DELEON FAMILY DE. After the change it should look like this: THE DELEON FAMILY DE.

Here is my code:

```
grep 'THE DELEON FAMILY DE' all_boros.txt | sed 's/"THE DELEON FAMILY DE/THE DELEON FAMILY DE'
```

This is the error I get:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 44: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: sed  's/"THE DELEON FAMILY DE/THE DELEON FAMILY DE/g' data

Comment: sed: can't read data: No such file or directory

Comment: sed 's/"THE DELEON FAMILY DE/THE DELEON FAMILY DE/g' all_boros.txt

Comment: I just ran it. But it didn't remove the extra double quote in front of name

Comment: can you show us some sample contents from all_boros.txt ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a the last `/` in the substitution command:

```
s/"THE DELEON FAMILY DE/THE DELEON FAMILY DE/
#                                           ^ Here
```

And you *don't* need grep at all and you don't need to repeat the replacement:

```
sed 's/"\(THE DELEON FAMILY DE\)/\1/' all_boros.txt
```

Dependent on your needs you might want to use the `g`lobal modifier, this will make the substitution command match multiply times for each line:

```
sed 's/"\(THE DELEON FAMILY DE\)/\1/g' all_boros.txt
```

And you can use `-i` to do in place edit:

```
sed -i.bak 's/"\(THE DELEON FAMILY DE\)/\1/g' all_boros.txt
#   ^ this will make a backup called all_boros.txt.bak while modifying the
#     original file
```

Comment: If you don't use the `grep`, then you'll need to suppress the non-matching lines in your `sed` program.  Probably the easiest way is to pass `-n` and then use `s///p` (`p`rint modifier).

Comment: @TobySpeight That's true That one slipped though my head. Thanks for clarifying :-)

Answer (score 2):

No need to grep and replace, Sed take care of it.

```
sed -i 's/"THE DELEON FAMILY DE/THE DELEON FAMILY DE/g' all_boros.txt
```

Comment: I tried it exactly the way you wrote it (copied and pasted), no grep. But the double quote is still there.

Comment: Use `-i` if you want to modify the file in place. Otherwise the modified file will be written to stdout.

Comment: now try , I have added "i" so that changes will get written to file.